# Binary Search Tree - remove function not changing the original tree

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I am trying to remove a root node in a binary search tree.

bst.remove(1) gives the correct output but it doesn't change the tree itself.

So if I check bst after calling bst.remove(1) the output is different. Why is it the case?

If I run `bst=bst.left||bst.right;`, I get the correct output, which leads me to believe that my function isn't changing the original tree in place.

```
remove(key) {
   return this.removeImpl(key, this);
  }

  removeImpl(key, node){  
    
      if (node != null) {
      if (key < node.value) {
        // Key might be in the left subtree.
        node.left = this.removeImpl(key, node.left);
      } else if (key > node.value) {
        node.right = this.removeImpl(key, node.right);
      } else {
        // Node found. 
        // Let's see if it has two children.
        
        
        if (node.left && node.right) {
          // Replace current node with 
          // predecessor data
          
          node.value = this.minimum(node.right);
          node.right = this.removeImpl(node.value, node.right);
        } else {
          // Only 1 child.
          // Let's return the child that's valid.
          
          node = node.left || node.right; //node to be removed becomes it's right or left child
    
        }
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

var bst=new BST(1);
bst.insert(2);
bst.insert(3);
bst.insert(4);

bst.remove(1);
```

Comment: Well the tree cannot replace itself, calling a method on it won't assign a different object to the `bst` variable. You'll need to write `bst = bst.remove(1);` to get a different root node stored in `bst`

Comment: It does seem to only be a problem for root. If I run ```bst.remove(2)``` the bst is changed in place

Comment: Yes it is, since `bst` does store the root node. You should consider using a separate class to represent the tree itself (which also makes it possible to represent an empty tree without a root node), then the tree `.remove()` method can easily change its `.rootnode` in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `bst.remove(1)` gives the correct output but it doesn't change the tree itself.

That is intended. What you call "the tree itself", is actually the root node. Your code doesn't have a concept of tree in a form of a separate class -- the tree is (only) *implied* by the root node. As the removal of a node is not a mutation of the removed node, but of other references, and the only reference you have to that root node is the `bst` variable, you need an *assignment* to `bst`. In the extreme case where the last node of a tree is removed, you'll expect `bst` to become `null`, so again, an *assignment* to `bst` is needed. As this `bst` variable is not a property of some class instance, you need to manage this assignment "yourself" in the main code.

Here is another way to analyse this situation:

The `removeImpl` function *relies on the caller* to attach the *returned* node at the right place. You can see this happening at every *recursive* call that is made by `removeImpl`... for example:

```
  node.left = this.removeImpl(key, node.left);
  node.right = this.removeImpl(key, node.right);
```

So we could say that the *caller* mutates the tree. If `removeImpl` is itself the caller (of a recursive call), then it performs the mutation itself, but also the *initial* caller of `removeImpl` (which is `remove`) does so:

```
return this.removeImpl(key, this);
```

Here we see that the responsibility to do something with the returned node is cascaded to the caller of `remove`. That caller should apply this principle, and that is were your current code is lacking. We see the call of `remove` here:

```
bst.remove(1)
```

But that call *ignores* the returned node. That is not how `remove` is supposed to be called. It should be called like this:

```
bst = bst.remove(1)
```

With that change, the code consistently uses the node returned by the `remove` and `removeImpl` methods to capture the change.

#### A two-class system

The above may look too verbose. If you want `bst.remove(1)` to do the job without any need to assign something to `bst`, then you should consider a two-class system instead of your current one-class implementation.

You would then rename your current `BST` class to `Node`, and create a second class which will be the container class, and can be named `BST`. When you rename `BST` to `Node`, don't forget to use that name also where you create nodes (like in the `insert` method, `new BST` should become `new Node`).

Then add:

```
class BST {
    constructor() {
        self.root = null; // Now the root is a property, not a global variable
    }
    insert(key) {
        if (self.root == null) self.root = new Node(key);
        else self.root.insert(key);
    }
    remove(key) {
        if (self.root) {
            // Now we mutate the container instance:
            self.root = self.root.remove(key);
        }
    }
}

var bst = new BST();
for (let value of [1, 2, 3, 4]) bst.insert(value);
bst.remove(1);
```